# Is it mentioned in the Vedas about the need or process of initiation?

Tags: vedas, mantras

The process by which a Guru initiates a disciple into a mantra is called Mantra Diksha.

Is it mentioned in the Vedas about this process or about other forms of Dikshas?

Comment: The need for a self realized Guru is mentioned in the Upanishads. "Atman, when taught by an inferior person, is not easily comprehended, because It is diversely regarded by disputants. **But when It is taught by him, who has become one with Atman, there can remain no more doubt about It. Atman is subtler than the subtlest and not to be known through arguments.**" Katha Upanishad I.ii.8

Comment: numerous places in the Upanishads.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Thanks but what about the "process of initiation".Is anything mentioned in that regard too?If so where?

Comment: No, not aware of any mention of the process. Some people have received their initiation in a dream, some in person, some in a vision. There are several stories where people have received a mantra in a dream from their guru. When they went to the guru and asked about the dream, he repeated the same mantra to them.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Thanks .I have also heard that a mantra can reveal itself on its own for a particular devotee/sadhaka.He can hear it coming out of no where, not necessarily in a dream but in a perfectly awake state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ganapati Atharva Seersha which is a part of Atharva Veda clearly mentions the need of initiation .

Quoting the needed portions from [here](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Ganapathi_Atharva_Seersha):

> Idham adharvaseersha masishyaya na dheyam, Yo yadhi mohad dhasyathi sa
>   papeeyan bhavathi, Sahasravarthanath yam yam kamam adheethe, Tham
>   thamanena sadhayeth.
>
> Meaning-**This adharva seersha should not be given, who is not a
>   disciple,** He who gives it due to passion, becomes a great sinner,
>   Thousand times repetition helps one get all that one wishes to get.

Answer (score 1):

No there is only one thing which is mentioned in Vedas (here in [**Atharva Veda**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av07105.htm))

## An Initiation formula

> Leaving humanity behind, making the heavenly word thy choice,
>     With all thy friends address thyself to furthering and guiding
>      men.

Comment: "Making the heavenly word thy choice" means?which heavenly word is being referred to?

Comment: It mean your purpose shouldn't just be humanity but to follow the words of ultimate reality ( refers to metaphysics, it means whatever is accepted as truth or Gyan of the reality of material world and universal power ) so that your friends can consider you as a guiding man.

Comment: So,if ,as you say, its not mentioned in the Vedas then why still we give utmost importance to the process of initiation?.People also say that unless you get a mantra from a living Guru it won't work properly.